# Takes hours to read and write 6000 pages in a PDF using Python

Tags: python

I have a large PDF file with 6303 pages. I've written a python program that looks for a specific ID within each page, renames the file with the ID, and saves it in another directory. There may be multiple pages with the same ID (subsequent pages) and those pages need to be saved as a single file. The program works well, but it takes a couple of hours to do the job. Is there any way I can optimize the code to speed up the process? I'm pretty new to Python and any help on this is much appreciated.

I've used pdfplumber and PyPDF2 libraries to get the task done. The reason I used pdfplumber is because PyPDF2 was not able to read my PDF document properly.

Thanks in advance.

```
import pdfplumber
import PyPDF2
import sys

searchTxt = 'personalnummer' 
Path = r'C:\Users\102398\OneDrive - Neeyamo Enterprise Solutions Pvt. Ltd\Work in progress_Allan\PDF Automation for SGRE\Inputs and Reference\Consolidated payslips.pdf'
outputPath = r'C:\Users\102398\OneDrive - Neeyamo Enterprise Solutions Pvt. Ltd\Work in progress_Allan\PDF Automation for SGRE\PDF Folder'
pages = []
strtPg = 0
c = 0

PayslipPdf = pdfplumber.open(Path)
    
if len(PayslipPdf.pages) < 2:
    firstPg = PayslipPdf.pages[0].extract_text().splitlines()
    for line in firstPg:
        if searchTxt in line.lower(): #search for personalnummer
           EEID = (line.split()[-1]) #get Employee ID
           newFileName = 'Payslip-' + EEID + '.pdf'
           pyPayslipPdf = open(Path,'rb')
           reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pyPayslipPdf)
           writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
           curPage = reader.getPage(0)
           writer.addPage(curPage)
           outputFile = open(outputPath + '\\' + newFileName, 'wb')
           writer.write(outputFile)
           outputFile.close()
           sys.exit()

firstPg = PayslipPdf.pages[0].extract_text().splitlines()
for line in firstPg:
    if searchTxt in line.lower(): #search for personalnummer
       EEID = (line.split()[-1]) #get Employee ID
       break
for page in range(len(PayslipPdf.pages)): #loop through pages
    c = c + 1
    pdfPage = PayslipPdf.pages[page].extract_text().splitlines() #Extract text
    for line in pdfPage:
        n = 0
        if searchTxt in line.lower(): #search for personalnummer
           CrID = (line.split()[-1]) #get Employee ID
           n = 1
           break
    if n == 1: 
       if page != len(PayslipPdf.pages)-1:     
          if EEID != CrID:
             newFileName = 'Payslip-' + EEID + '.pdf' 
             for i in range(strtPg,page):
                 pages.append(i)
             pyPayslipPdf = open(Path,'rb')
             reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pyPayslipPdf)
             writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
             for pg in pages: 
                 curPage = reader.getPage(pg)
                 writer.addPage(curPage)   
             outputFile = open(outputPath + '\\' + newFileName, 'wb')
             writer.write(outputFile)
             outputFile.close()
             pages.clear()
             EEID = CrID
             strtPg = page
          
       elif page == len(PayslipPdf.pages)-1:
            print('entered the last page')
            if EEID != CrID:
               newFileName = 'Payslip-' + EEID + '.pdf' 
               for i in range(strtPg,page):
                   pages.append(i)
               pyPayslipPdf = open(Path,'rb')
               reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pyPayslipPdf)
               writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
               for pg in pages: 
                   curPage = reader.getPage(pg)
                   writer.addPage(curPage)   
               outputFile = open(outputPath + '\\' + newFileName, 'wb')
               writer.write(outputFile)
               outputFile.close()
               pages.clear()

               newFileName = 'Payslip-' + CrID + '.pdf' 
               pages.append(page)
               pyPayslipPdf = open(Path,'rb')
               reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pyPayslipPdf)
               writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
               for pg in pages: 
                   curPage = reader.getPage(pg)
                   writer.addPage(curPage)   
               outputFile = open(outputPath + '\\' + newFileName, 'wb')
               writer.write(outputFile)
               outputFile.close()
               
            elif EEID == CrID:
                 newFileName = 'Payslip-' + EEID + '.pdf' 
                 for i in range(strtPg,page+1):
                     pages.append(i)  
                 pyPayslipPdf = open(Path,'rb')
                 reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pyPayslipPdf)
                 writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
                 for pg in pages: 
                     curPage = reader.getPage(pg)
                     writer.addPage(curPage)   
                 outputFile = open(outputPath + '\\' + newFileName, 'wb')
                 writer.write(outputFile)
                 outputFile.close()
          
print(str(c) + ' pages were processed')
```

Comment: what is the format of data inside the pdf, is it tabular

Comment: can you share the pdf?

Comment: Hi, it is not in a tabular format. I was not able to extract any tables from it.

Comment: apologies, unfortunately, I cannot share the pdf. The file contains some confidential information. I might get into trouble if I do that :)

Comment: Ok, it makes it harder to help you then. Anyways. I think you can use regex to identify the ID on each page and then get rid of some of all your for loops.

Comment: @mama sure, will try that. Also, I was observing the destination folder where all the files are copied to. The code runs at a consistent speed for about 1500 pages and then it slows down (actually it takes a pause every few seconds before writing the subsequent files). Any reason this happens?

Comment: You memory might reach the max at that point.

Comment: Another thing is that PyPDF2 is an old version https://github.com/claird/PyPDF4 this is the new one

Comment: @mama Thanks a lot. Will try PyPDF4 and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just came up with a solution to this problem that is relatively faster. Apparently, the problem seems to be the total number of pages in the pdf (6303). When I tried to read and extract pages from a pdf that had about a 100 pages, python did it in less than a few secs. Hence I wrote a function to split the pdf pages by a certain number (500 in this case) and extracted the pages based on the IDs from those chunked up versions with 500 pages. That got the job done in about 15 to 20 mins.

```
import pdfplumber
import PyPDF2
import sys
import os

searchTxt = 'personalnummer'

SplitInpPath = r'C:\Users\102398\OneDrive - Neeyamo Enterprise Solutions Pvt. Ltd\Work in progress_Allan\PDF Automation for SGRE\Inputs and Reference\Consolidated payslips.pdf'
SplitOutPath = r'C:\Users\102398\OneDrive - Neeyamo Enterprise Solutions Pvt. Ltd\Work in progress_Allan\PDF Automation for SGRE\Split Pages'

def PdfSplitter(filePath, pgs, SrTxt, OutputPath):
    pdfFile = open(filePath,'rb')
    strtpg = 0   
    numpgs = pgs
    n = 0

    PayslipPdf = pdfplumber.open(filePath)
    reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)
    totalPages = reader.numPages
    
    while numpgs <= totalPages:
        writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
        for i in range(strtpg,numpgs):
            curPage = reader.getPage(i)
            writer.addPage(curPage)
            if i+1 != totalPages:
               if i+1 == numpgs:
                  Lastpg = PayslipPdf.pages[i].extract_text().splitlines()
                  for line in Lastpg:
                      if SrTxt in line.lower(): #search for personalnummer
                         EmpID = (line.split()[-1]) #get Employee ID
                         break
                  CurID = EmpID
                  while CurID == EmpID:
                        i = i + 1
                        CurPg = PayslipPdf.pages[i].extract_text().splitlines()
                        for line in CurPg:
                            if SrTxt in line.lower(): #search for personalnummer
                               CurID = (line.split()[-1]) #get Employee ID
                               break
                        if CurID == EmpID:   
                           curPage = reader.getPage(i)
                           writer.addPage(curPage)
                     
        outputFile = open(OutputPath + '\\Output_' + str(int(i+1)) + '.pdf', 'wb')
        writer.write(outputFile)
        outputFile.close()

        if numpgs == totalPages:
           break
        else:   
            strtpg = i
            numpgs = numpgs + pgs
        if numpgs > totalPages:
           numpgs = numpgs - (numpgs-totalPages)

PdfSplitter(SplitInpPath, 500, searchTxt, SplitOutPath)           

Path = r'C:\Users\102398\OneDrive - Neeyamo Enterprise Solutions Pvt. Ltd\Work in progress_Allan\PDF Automation for SGRE\Split Pages'
outputPath = r'C:\Users\102398\OneDrive - Neeyamo Enterprise Solutions Pvt. Ltd\Work in progress_Allan\PDF Automation for SGRE\PDF Folder'
pages = []
strtPg = 0
c = 0



fileName = os.listdir(Path)

for file in fileName:
    PayslipPdf = pdfplumber.open(Path + '\\' + file)
    print(Path + '\\' + file)
    
    if len(PayslipPdf.pages) < 2:
       firstPg = PayslipPdf.pages[0].extract_text().splitlines()
       for line in firstPg:
           if searchTxt in line.lower(): #search for personalnummer
              EEID = (line.split()[-1]) #get Employee ID
              newFileName = 'Payslip-' + EEID + '.pdf'
              pyPayslipPdf = open(Path + '\\' + file, 'rb')
              reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pyPayslipPdf)
              writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
              curPage = reader.getPage(0)
              writer.addPage(curPage)
              outputFile = open(outputPath + '\\' + newFileName, 'wb')
              writer.write(outputFile)
              outputFile.close()
              sys.exit()

    firstPg = PayslipPdf.pages[0].extract_text().splitlines()
    for line in firstPg:
        if searchTxt in line.lower(): #search for personalnummer
           EEID = (line.split()[-1]) #get Employee ID
           break
    for page in range(len(PayslipPdf.pages)): #loop through pages
        #c = c + 1
        length = len(PayslipPdf.pages)
        pdfPage = PayslipPdf.pages[page].extract_text().splitlines() #Extract text
        for line in pdfPage:
            n = 0
            if searchTxt in line.lower(): #search for personalnummer
               CrID = (line.split()[-1]) #get Employee ID
               n = 1
               break
        if n == 1: 
           if page != len(PayslipPdf.pages)-1:     
              if EEID != CrID:
                 newFileName = 'Payslip-' + EEID + '.pdf' 
                 for i in range(strtPg,page):
                     pages.append(i)
                 pyPayslipPdf = open(Path + '\\' + file, 'rb')
                 reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pyPayslipPdf)
                 writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
                 for pg in pages: 
                     curPage = reader.getPage(pg)
                     writer.addPage(curPage)   
                 outputFile = open(outputPath + '\\' + newFileName, 'wb')
                 writer.write(outputFile)
                 outputFile.close()
                 pages.clear()
                 EEID = CrID
                 strtPg = page
          
           elif page == len(PayslipPdf.pages)-1:
                print('entered the last page')
                if EEID != CrID:
                   newFileName = 'Payslip-' + EEID + '.pdf' 
                   for i in range(strtPg,page):
                       pages.append(i)
                   pyPayslipPdf = open(Path + '\\' + file, 'rb')
                   reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pyPayslipPdf)
                   writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
                   for pg in pages: 
                       curPage = reader.getPage(pg)
                       writer.addPage(curPage)   
                   outputFile = open(outputPath + '\\' + newFileName, 'wb')
                   writer.write(outputFile)
                   outputFile.close()
                   pages.clear()

                   newFileName = 'Payslip-' + CrID + '.pdf' 
                   pages.append(page)
                   pyPayslipPdf = open(Path + '\\' + file, 'rb')
                   reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pyPayslipPdf)
                   writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
                   for pg in pages: 
                       curPage = reader.getPage(pg)
                       writer.addPage(curPage)   
                   outputFile = open(outputPath + '\\' + newFileName, 'wb')
                   writer.write(outputFile)
                   outputFile.close()
                   strtPg = 0
                   pages.clear()
               
                elif EEID == CrID:
                     newFileName = 'Payslip-' + EEID + '.pdf' 
                     for i in range(strtPg,page+1):
                         pages.append(i)  
                     pyPayslipPdf = open(Path + '\\' + file, 'rb')
                     reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pyPayslipPdf)
                     writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
                     for pg in pages: 
                         curPage = reader.getPage(pg)
                         writer.addPage(curPage)   
                     outputFile = open(outputPath + '\\' + newFileName, 'wb')
                     writer.write(outputFile)
                     outputFile.close()
                     strtPg = 0
                     pages.clear()
```